# Define a nested view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a website by AngularJS, `index.html` has

```
<body>
    <ui-view ng-cloak></ui-view>
</body>
```

And in `angularApp.js`:

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: '/htmls/home.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        }
        .state('help', {
            url: '/help',
            templateUrl: '/htmls/help.html',
            controller: 'HelpCtrl'
        }   
}])
```

In `home.html` and `help.html` (along with other pages), I always have a same navigation bar on the top of the page. So I want to avoid from repeating the code and make a `/htmls/header.html` and a controller `NavCtrl`. As a result, I will be able to write `<div ui-view="header"></div>` in these htmls.

Does anyone know how to modify my `angularApp.js` and maybe `index.html` to let them accept the nested `header` view?

Answer (score 0):

Update code inside your config block to:

```
$stateProvider      
  .state('home',{       
    views: {        
      'header': {       
        templateUrl: '/htmls/header.html',      
        controller: 'NavCtrl'
      },        
      'content': {      
        templateUrl: '/htmls/home.html',        
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      }     
    }       
  })
  .state('help',{       
    views: {        
      'header': {       
        templateUrl: '/htmls/header.html',      
        controller: 'NavCtrl'
      },
      'content': {      
        templateUrl: '/htmls/help.html',        
        controller: 'HelpCtrl'  
      }     
    }       
  })
```

And in index.html use it as below, where now home.html, help.html can have only content without header html

```
<body>
    <div ui-view="header"></div>
    <div ui-view="content"></div>
</body>
```

Follow [**Official docs**](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views)

Comment: Thank you... I want to keep `<body><ui-view ng-cloak></ui-view</body>` in `index.html`, because there are other pages without the header. Then what should I do?

Comment: @SoftTimur For those pages just have another header1.html containing no nav elements (only plain blank background div). Or you can just skip header view for those states.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `ui-view`, use a component:

```
̶<̶d̶i̶v̶ ̶u̶i̶-̶v̶i̶e̶w̶=̶"̶h̶e̶a̶d̶e̶r̶"̶>̶<̶/̶d̶i̶v̶>̶
<my-header></my-header>
```

JS

```
app.component("myHeader", {
    templateUrl: '/htmls/header.html',      
    controller: 'NavCtrl'
});
```